# Use of undefined constant Php version error

Tags: php

I'm getting an error when migrating from php 7.4 to 8.1. Is the reason below? but how do i fix it

PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS’ - assumed '‘EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) /wp-config.php on line 32

Comment: or this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317562/how-can-i-resolve-the-php-notice-constant-empty-trash-days-already-defined

Comment: Your question is a bit odd: if you're getting an error in PHP 8.1, why not show that error, rather than the warning shown in PHP 7.4? Either way, the error is fairly clear: you haven't told PHP what the value of EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS should be. Without more information about your code - i.e. where you *expect* that value to come from - there's not much more we can tell you.